# homomorphism with different rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ring-homomorphism

say we have two commutative rings S and R and S$\subset$ R (subring). Say we have A, B modules over S and A', B' modules over R.

does it make sense to define a **homomorphism** between $Hom_S$(A,B) and $Hom_R$(A',B')?

Comment: The hom-sets are abelian groups, so you could define this homomorphism as an abelian group morphism.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen: Even more: both sets are naturally $S$-modules - but this is not the issue here. The question is: *how* do you define such a morphism?

Comment: I didn't say this, but I was actually assuming there was already a bijection between $Hom_S$(A,B) and $Hom_R$(A',B').

Comment: yeah, so I think without telling you explicitly what the map is we won't be able to determine if it can be a homomorphism...

Answer (score 0):

No, not in general. Even when $R=S$ there is no natural way of *extending* a morphism in $\hom (A', B')$ to one in $\hom (A,B)$. The other direction is equally problematic: there may exist morphisms in $\hom (A,B)$ which do not take $A'$ into $B'$ - in which case there is no way of making them *restrict* to morphisms in $\hom (A',B')$ (a concrete example being for $A=B=R= \Bbb Q$ and $A' = B' = S = \Bbb Z$: define $f : A \to B$ by $f(a) = \dfrac a 2$ and notice that $f(A') \not\subseteq B'$).